# Ethereum wallet stuck on loading

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, windows

I have installed `Ethereum Wallet` and switch it to the `Ropsten Testnet` after first start, it synced all blocks.

After restart I am trying to run it, but it stuck on loading splash.

[image]

I am on `Windows 7`, how can I fix this problem and run this application?